# Function to array without back to back duplicates

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops, conditional-statements

I want to use a function that takes a string sequence of either numbers or letters and returns those values in an array with no back to back duplicates but can have duplicates just not back to back.

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    iterable = list(iterable)
    changed = []
    for i in range(len(iterable)):
        if (iterable[i] != iterable[i+1]) :
            changed.append(iterable[i])
        break;
    return changed
```

Comment: This is returning only the first value in the sequence but then doesn't loop back through and grab the rest.

Comment: Could you provide an example input, and an expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Doing a very small change from your code, we can do this very easily and compactly:

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    changed = []
    before = None
    for char in iterable:
        if before != char:
            before = char
            changed.append(char)
    return changed

x = "122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999"
z = "Mississippi"
print(unique_in_order(x))
print(unique_in_order(z))
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['M', 'i', 's', 'i', 's', 'i', 'p', 'i']
```

Due to you only expecting the function to get a string, we can assume that when we iterate over it, no comparison against `None` will ever be `True`. That in turn sets the new character into `before`.